# jQuery refactoring

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, refactoring

I often spend 10-20 minutes looking at pieces of jQuery to find a way of shortening the code that's there.

Now this piece of code I've been looking at time and time again but just want to know how people would go about refactoring it or if indeed they would.

```
$("#tabs ul li").first().addClass("activeTab");
$("#tabs div").hide().first().show();
$("#tabs ul li a").click(function(){
    $("#tabs div").hide();
    $("#tabs").find($(this).attr('href')).show();
});
```

This is more a question of curiosity that a cry for help as I'm trying to better my coding skills in jQuery.

/* EDIT

Link attached [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCLsG/)

End Result from all your fabulous suggestions is.

```
var $c = $("#tabs"), $t = $c.find("li"), $d = $c.find("div");
$d.not(":first").hide();
$t.find("a").click(function() {
    $d.hide().filter($(this).attr('href')).show();
}).closest("li").first().addClass("activeTab");
```

Comment: Without seeing the markup, and fully understanding what you're trying to accomplish, there is no way to optimize this properly.

Comment: The only thing I'd do is to invert the order of the first two statements: I always put similar things together, so `#tabs ul li` is similar to `#tabs ul li a`, and so they go one after the other, while `#tabs div` is something else, that can go in the first line "alone"

Comment: Your first selector could be written as `$('#tabs ul li:first')` and the call to `.first()` could be dropped. Other than that, I don't see anything that I would find in need of refactoring, but then I prefer readable code over terse code. As James points out, if it's optimization you're after, we can't comment on performance without seeing your markup.

Comment: I'll stick a jsfiddle up so you can have a look as well. I'm not so much after optimization just the refactoring of code in this instance. I'll get that jsfiddle sorted now

Comment: @Zweer I've just read that the `.first()` function is faster than the `:first` selector as the latter involves selector parsing. I'm really surprised to be honest.

http://api.jquery.com/first/#comment-37524554

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refactor this as follows. There is no need to make jQuery object each time, make a reference to it for future use.

```
    var $tabs = $("#tabs");

    $tabs.find("li:first").addClass("activeTab");
    $tabs.find('div').not(':first').hide();
    $tabs.find("a").click(function() {
        $("#tabs div").hide().filter($(this).attr('href')).show();
    })
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was after. My understanding of sticking the var $tabs is so it doesn't call the DOM quite so often? Is that true?

Comment: It should only access the DOM once, except for the `$("tabs div").not()` call. The `find` calls will look for the markup within the `$tabs` variable.

Comment: Thanks I've implemented a mixture of your solution and fegemo's with the extra declarations

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor the selectors, so traversing the Dom would be less costly. It would be something like:

```
var $tabsControl = $("#tabs"),
    $tabs = $tabsControl.find("ul > li"),
    $tabsContent = $tabsControl.find("div");

$tabs.first().addClass("activeTab");
$tabsContent.hide().first().show();
$tabs.find("a").click(function() {
    $tabsContent.hide();
    $tabsControl.find($(this).attr("href")).show();
});
```

Comment: I liked this version the most but unfortunately even with bug fixing and a quick inspection I couldn't get it working.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I verified now that it's properly working.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think this code is OK, but would refactor `$("#tabs div").hide().first().show();` just to make it more readable, maybe:

```
$("#tabs div").not(":first").hide();
```